# Swift: decode data into object which is an inherited class comes error

Tags: swift, inheritance, decode, decodable

I'm working on decode data into object. The model classes are:

```
class ZZBaseObj: Codable {
    var fid: String

    init() {
        fid = ""

    }
    private enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey {
        case id
    }
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)    
        fid = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.id)

    }
}

class ZZFileObj: ZZBaseObj {
    var columns:[String]
    override init() {
        columns = [String]()
        super.init()
    }
    private enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey {
        case columns
    }
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        columns = try values.decode([String].self, forKey: CodingKeys.columns)
        try super.init(from: decoder)

    }
}
```

The json data looks like:

```
(
{
    columns =     (
        "first name",
        last,
        subject,
        address,
        age
    );
    id = "1lYc8iIzMdfdfgjGYMKwO4-X3fWe-4GlzfQ-dfs";

},
{
    columns =     (
        "2018/1/30",
        100,
        "9800"
    );
    id = "1fdsafdgfQL-fdfdf-fdf";
}
)
```

When I try to use `JSONDecoder()` to decode the data into object, there is no error. I get the resultArray, and in the console, I can see the elements. Then it comes to `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when comes to following code:

```
let obj = resultArray[0]
let content = obj.columns //---------error happens here
```

I understand it is a memory issue, but when I try to set breakpoint here, and in lldb input:

```
po obj.columns
```

It prints out the content of the columns.
This confuses me. As the class `ZZFileObj` is inherited from `ZZBaseObj`, and I guess there is something missing for inheritance. I try to make a new class which includes fid, and columns, and that comes no error. However, there a common attribute so I need such a base class for the models.
Please help take a look.

Comment: "When I try to use JSONDecoder() to decode the data into object" But how? Your objects don't even compile for me: "CodingKey case 'id' does not match any stored properties".

Comment: And your JSON appears to be invalid.

Comment: @matt, the data is a sample, and not say in JSON format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue in `Swift 4.1`.

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7090

You can fix for now by removing `Codable` conformance from base `class`. And once the issue is fixed in coming version of `Xcode/Swift`, you can revert back.

Here is how you can achieve this with minimal effort to revert back in future by moving `Codable` to base `class`. You can also try in beta version of `Xcode 10` where your current code might work as expected.

```
class ZZBaseObj {
    var id: String

    init() {
        id = ""

    }
    private enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey {
        case id
    }
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.id)

    }
}

class ZZFileObj: ZZBaseObj, Codable {
    var columns:[String]
    override init() {
        columns = [String]()
        super.init()
    }
    private enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey {
        case columns
    }
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        columns = try values.decode([String].self, forKey: CodingKeys.columns)
        try super.init(from: decoder)

    }
}

let json = """
[
{
  "columns":["some text 1", "some text 2"],
  "id": "1lYc8iIzMdfdfgjGYMKwO4-X3fWe-4GlzfQ-dfs"
},
{
  "columns":["some text 3", "some text 4"],
  "id": "1lYc8iIzMdfdfgjGYMKwO4-X3fWe-4GlzfQ-dfs"
}
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let obj = try! decoder.decode([ZZFileObj].self, from: json)
print(obj.first!.columns)
print(obj.first!.id)
```

Output:

```
["some text 1", "some text 2"]
1lYc8iIzMdfdfgjGYMKwO4-X3fWe-4GlzfQ-dfs
```

Comment: you did point the right direction! One more question is that how do you know there is such a kind of bug?